Ambiguity in path integral approach to 2D Liouville gravity, versus operator formalism
The 2D Liouville quantum gravity is, since 2014, known to be a complete theory of quantum gravity for which we can derive all n-point correlation functions (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.7318). The n-point functions are constructed as:
\begin{equation}
G^{(n)}(\{\alpha_i\}_i|\{z_i\}_i) \equiv \left\langle \prod_i V_{\alpha_i} (z_i)\right\rangle_\mathrm{L.},\,\,\, V_{\alpha_i}(z_i)\equiv\, :e^{2\alpha_i \varphi(z_i)}:
\end{equation}
Where $V$ is called a "vertex operator", $:-:$ is the normal ordering, $\alpha_i=\frac{Q}{2}+iP_i$ (with $P_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $Q$ is related to the central charge of the theory). Moreover, $\varphi(z)$ is the Liouville field operator, the field upon which one integrates over in the path integral approach.
In the path integral approach, this correlator is given by:
\begin{equation}
G^{(n)}(\{\alpha_i\}_i|\{z_i\}_i) \equiv \int \mathcal{D}\varphi\,e^{-S_\mathrm{L.}[\varphi]} \prod_i e^{2\alpha_i \varphi(z_i)}.
\end{equation}
We can see that $\varphi$ is now a function and not an operator, by definition of the path integral.
My problem arises due to this definition because, since $\varphi(z)$ is now a function, one could in principle use the properties of the exponentials to have, for example:
\begin{equation}
e^{2\alpha_i \varphi(z)}e^{2\alpha_j \varphi(z)} = e^{2(\alpha_i + \alpha_j)\varphi(z)}.
\end{equation}
But, $V_{\alpha_i}(z)V_{\alpha_j}(z) \neq V_{\alpha_i+\alpha_j}(z)$, due to the normal ordering. In fact, we have $\langle V_{\alpha_i}(z)V_{\alpha_j}(z) \rangle_\mathrm{L.} \sim  \lim_{y\rightarrow z}|z-y|^{-2\Delta_{ij}}$, which diverges while, according to this PSE question, $\langle V_{\alpha_i+\alpha_j}(z) \rangle_\mathrm{L.}=0$.
What is happening here? Am I misunderstanding how correlation functions are calculated for the theory in the path integral approach? Ideally, I would like to use only the path integral approach, where it seems we can glue together vertex functions $e^{2\alpha \varphi(z)}$, but it seems wrong in light of the operator formalism...
Putting it more succinctly, my question is: Is there any ambiguity in the definition of correlation functions in 2D Liouville gravity in the path integral approach, and if so, how can I overcome it?

Are you aware that the fields $\varphi(z_i)$ are inserted at different points $z_i\neq z_j$ on the sphere. So you cannot simply sum the exponents together. The primary fields of quantum Liouville field theory inserted at the punctures constitute a regular ramification of the associated spectral cover because they are primary fields of an affine $sl_2$-algebra. See for example at quantum Drinfeld-Sokolev reduction.  Those punctures can collide to form irregular operators, so called Gaiotto states. However, this is much more involved and can be better understood with spectral covers or Seiberg-Witten curves also due to Donagi-Witten.

Thank you for your answer, and the keywords (I will check them later). However, from the path integral approach, nothing prevents me from inserting two fields at the same point. This is where my confusion comes from... Can you expand a bit on your answer regarding this aspect of the path integral approach?

I am not sure if I understand you correctly but $O(z_i)=e^{2\alpha_i\varphi(z_i)}$ is a local operaor and the product inside the path integral is an operator product. Since the operators in Liouville field theory form a vertex operator algebra as mentioned above, their product is a sum (see OPE) with radius of convergence equal to the distance between their locations. So if you want anything meaningful to be computed you should avoid collisions between operators.

But, the path integral has only classical fields though. At least, this is how it works for all the rest of QFT, so what do you mean by "the product inside the path integral is an operator product"? Maybe there is a special treatment of the function $e^{2\alpha \varphi(z)}$ that prevents us from using the properties of the exponential? Like an integral averaging over a small circle of radius $\epsilon$ around $z$ and hence forcing us to make the change $\varphi(z) \leadsto \varphi_\epsilon(z)$?

It seems I have found an answer to my question in the articles https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.00829 , and https://arxiv.org/abs/2404.02001 . The answer is that the construction I provided is not rigorous at all and that one has to first average the Liouville field like so:
\begin{equation}
\varphi \leadsto \varphi_\epsilon \equiv \frac{1}{2\pi}\oint d\theta\,\varphi(z+\epsilon e^{i\theta}) 
\end{equation}
The idea is to ultimately take the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. Second, to have a field with meaningful variance, $\langle \varphi_\epsilon(z)^2 \rangle$, one has to "normal order" its exponential. This is not a normal order as per operators in QFT, but a prescription on the Liouville field one imposes like so:
\begin{equation}
V_{\alpha,\epsilon}(z)\equiv \epsilon^{2\alpha^2}e^{2\alpha \varphi_\epsilon(z)} = \epsilon^{2\alpha^2}e^{2\alpha \varphi_\epsilon(z)-2\alpha^2 \langle \varphi_\epsilon(z)^2\rangle}
\end{equation}
Where the Liouville field is defined as $\varphi_\epsilon(z)\equiv X_\epsilon(z)+c+\frac{Q}{2}(\ln \sigma)_\epsilon$, with $X$ the field upon which one integrates in the path integral, and $\sigma$ is the 2D Fubini-Study metric (and $c$ is a constant).
So, one can see that introducing the normal ordering destroys the property $e^{2\alpha_i X(z)}e^{2\alpha_j X(z)} = e^{2(\alpha_i+\alpha_j) X(z)}$. This is because, $\alpha_i^2+\alpha_j^2 \neq (\alpha_i+\alpha_j)^2$. This clears up my confusion.

Lets review some basic material on Vertex opertors in the path integral setting.
For a Euclidean Bosonic scalar field in the whole of ${\mathbb R}^2$
we have the Gaussian functional  integral  identity
$$
\frac 1 Z \int d[\varphi]\exp\left( - \int\left\{ \frac 12 |\nabla \varphi|^2 + iJ({\bf r}) \varphi\right\} d^2{\bf r}\right)\\=
\exp\left \{  - \frac 12 \int  J({\bf r}_1)G({\bf r}_1-{\bf r}_2) J({\bf r}_2)d^2{\bf r}_1 d^2 {\bf r}_2\right\}
$$ where
$$
G({\bf r}) = -\frac 1{2\pi} \ln (\mu |{\bf r}|)
$$
is the Green function of the Laplacian
$$
-\nabla^2 G({\bf r}) = \delta^2({\bf r}).
$$
Now, strictly speaking,
there is no such $G({\bf r})$, because the  momentum space
integral
$$
G({\bf r})\stackrel{\rm ?}{=} \int \frac {d^2 {\bf k}}{(2\pi)^2}\frac{e^{i{\bf
k}\cdot {\bf r}}}{{ \bf k}^2},
$$
is logarithmically divergent at small ${\bf k}$. However, by
introducing a small mass $\mu$ to serve as an  infra-red cut-off,
we can approximate
$$
G({\bf r})\to \int \frac {d^2 {\bf k}}{(2\pi)^2}\frac{e^{i{\bf
k}\cdot {\bf r}}}{{ \bf k}^2+\mu^2}= \frac 1{2\pi} K_0(\mu|{\bf r}|)=-\frac 1{2\pi}\ln \mu |{\bf r}|+const+O(\mu
|{\bf r}|).
$$
The $const.$ can be absorbed into a renormalization
condition, so we will actually use  the simpler expression
$G({\bf r})=-\frac 1{2\pi}\ln \mu |{\bf r}|$.  All  quantities of interest
will be infra-red finite,  so we can  always take the limit $\mu
\to 0$ at the end of the calculation.
When
$$
J({\bf r}) = \alpha \delta^2({\bf r}-{\bf r}_1)-\alpha \delta^2({\bf r}-{\bf r}_2) )
$$
we find that
$$
\langle e^{i\alpha\varphi({\bf r}_1)}e^{-i\alpha\varphi({\bf r}_2)}\rangle= \exp\left\{-\frac{\alpha^2}{2\pi}\ln|{\bf r}_1-{\bf r}_2|\right\}=  \frac 1{|{\bf r}_1-{\bf r}_2|^{\alpha^2/2\pi}}.
$$
Two conventions need to be explained regarding  this formula.
Firstly, in order to get a finite answer, we  did not include the
divergent self energy factors coming from the terms in the
exponent  where the  Green function is to be evaluated at $0$.
This means that we have really evaluated  correlators of the
``normal ordered'' exponentials $:\!\!\exp \{\pm i\alpha\varphi({\bf r})\}\!\!:$.
The omission of these divergences accounts for the dimensional
mismatch between the right and left hand sides.  The
normal-ordered exponential,  unlike its un-ordered counterpart,
is not dimensionless. Secondly, we have dropped reference to
$\mu$.  If we {had} included a self-energy Green function in
the form $\frac 1{2\pi}\ln \mu a$, with $a$ a short distance
cut-off, the infra-red cut-off $\mu$ would have canceled between
the UV finite and the UV divergent terms leaving only a power,
$|a|^{\alpha^2/2\pi}$, in the numerator of the right hand side of the correlator. When present, this power serves to make the overall
expression dimensionless. Normal-ordering provides a
multiplicative renormalization of the operator which removes it.
Provided the total "charge'', $\sum \alpha_i$, is zero, there is
no    $\mu$, dependence in  any correlator composed of operators of the
form $\exp i\alpha_i\varphi$.  For a correlator where this
condition is not satisfied, the $\mu$'s  give rise to an overall
factor
$$
C=\mu^{\left(\sum\alpha_i\right)^2/4\pi}, 
$$
which has a positive exponent. This tends to zero as the cut-off
is removed,  meaning that ``non-neutral'' correlators  vanish.
In particlular the vev of a single vertex opertor $\langle e^{i\alpha \varphi(x)}\rangle$ is zero for any $\alpha$

Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, my confusion does not seem to come from this aspect of the theory (at least to me). As I explained in my own answer, my confusion is cleared up when considering a more rigorous approach to the Liouville expectation value (circle-averaging the Liouville field and then "normal ordering" it). In particular, as the paper cowritten by Witten (right above eq(2.19) ), I mention in my answer shows, we have $\mathbb{E}[:e^Y:]=1$, due to the normal ordering prescription.
